# Configure webpack to use relative paths for Cordova apps

Tags: cordova, webpack, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

In order to use the same React code base in Cordova I have to add a `./` prefix to all assets and scripts relative paths.

For example this logo gets correctly loaded in a browser but not inside a Cordova App since the latter uses the `file` protocol:

```
                 <div>
                    <img
                      className="PaymentIcons"
                      src="/assets/Visa.png"
                      alt="mastercard logo"
                    />
                  </div>
```

Adding the `./` prefix when the app is built for Cordova does the trick.

**QUESTION** now is.. what is the best way to **add this URL prefix programmatically using WebPack**?